# Passing session information with WebObjects

Tags: java, session, cookies, sessionid, webobjects

My team's lead developer is trying to figure out a way to pass session information in some other way than via the URL when using WebObjects.

Our site was built using web objects, but the problem we're now having is that when bloggers blog about us and post links from our site in their blog posts, the URL typically includes session information it and isn't valid for anyone other than the person who copied the link in the first place, Bloggers trying to point people to *www.example-dot-com* are instead blogging links such as 
*www.example-dot-com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/example.woa/wo/0.11.3.8*

Anyone have any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues here. Firstly, if you want to remove the session ID from the URL (which is the default), you override `WOSession.setStoresIDsInCookies()` to return `true` and `WOSession.setStoresIDsInURLs()` to return `false`.

However, your example URL doesn't have a session ID, so presumably you've figured that out. There are then a number of ways to get friendlier URLs, the easiest of which is probably to use [direct actions](http://davidleber.net/?p=63). You could then have a URL more like `www.example-dot-com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/example.woa/wa/someTarget`.

Finally, [Project Wonder](https://github.com/projectwonder/wonder) provides [full support for URL re-writing](http://lists.apple.com/archives/webobjects-dev/2012/Sep/msg00172.html), to the extent that you could have something more like `www.example-dot-com/someTarget`.